# Docker for Windows Host Network Stack Use

Tags: docker, ros

Currently, I'm working on a project where we are using ROS, Bebop_autonomy, and OpenCV to control a Parrot Bebop2 autonomously. The machines we use in the workspace are running Ubuntu 14.04.5, and I can start a container using an image

I created with "docker run -it --network=host username/image". After configuring everything inside the container, the bebop_autonomy node is fine and can communicate on the Bebop's network perfectly. When you run ip addr in both the container and host machine, they show the same address, as you'd expect.

However, when trying to run it on my Windows machine, the ip is different than the host machine, and I'm never receiving any ACK packets when I try to communicate with the Bebop. I'm assuming this is because the packets aren't being sent to the right ip, or they aren't being forwarded correctly.

I have tried creating my own network and setting the ip manually with "docker network create" and passing it in to the run command as an argument, but I can't seem to get it to work at all. I've also tried creating different switches in the Hyper-V manager, but nothing I've read in the last few days has helped me figure this out.

I've got a good handle on how docker works, but most of the reference material I see is talking about a host that already runs linux. If I can't figure this out, it's almost useless for us to continue with docker in the first place.

Is there any way to configure Docker for Windows to work in the same way that Docker works on Linux when providing --network=host?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up achieving what I wanted by creating a separate network in Hyper-V manager, setting that network to only use an external wifi-adapter, and running the container using that network. There has to be a better way though.

Comment: Have you found a better solution to running docker with network=host on windows?

Comment: No. I'm sure there's probably a way to do it, but I can't get it.

Comment: How did you set  the container to use  that network?

Comment: @dsaydon The container that is spun up automatically uses it since you've set the VM to use the other adapter. At least, I believe that's how it was. There might be a better way to do it, but this was the only way I was able to get it to work on Windows.